# Issue with resizing of TextArea in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am having an issue with re-sizing a Text Area in the Chrome Browser.  When I re-size the Text Area to be taller and then re-size back to its normal size, the div does not re-size back to its normal size. The issue is caused because i am using "style="display: table" Does anyone know of a workaround for this?  You should be able to replicate my issue with the code below at http://jsfiddle.net/uJ7U6/

```
<div style="display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div style="display: table-cell;">
            <span style="font-weight: bold">TextArea 1</span>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;">
            <span class="dialogControlLabel">TextArea 2</span>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;">
            <span style="font-weight: bold">TextArea 3</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div style="display: table-cell;">
            <textarea id="txtTextArea1" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;">
            <textarea id="txtTextArea2" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;">
            <textarea id="txtTextArea3" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div style="display: table-cell;">
            <span class="dialogControlLabel">TextArea 4</span>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;">
            <span class="dialogControlLabel">TextArea 5</span>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;">
            <span class="dialogControlLabel">TextArea 6</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div style="display: table-cell;">
            <textarea id="txtTextArea4" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;">
            <textarea id="txtTextArea5" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;">
            <textarea id="txtTextArea6" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please take a minute to set up a working fiddle (www.jsfiddle.net) with your code

Comment: I added the fiddle link to the post.  Thanks for the advice.  http://jsfiddle.net/uJ7U6/

Comment: Working perfectly for me.

Comment: Thanks for your input David.  Your post inspired me to check if I had the latest version of Chrome.   Once chrome updated, the bug was fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replicate the problem in your fiddle. I am using Chrome version Version 29.0.1547.76.

All I had to do was add in a CSS declaration for textarea.

```
textarea {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

This let me resize any of the textareas, and have the `<td>`'s respond to the changes in size.

e.g. Going from small to large to small.

Test it out on your revised fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/uJ7U6/1/